# Telerik control equivalent to ajax:DragPanelExtender?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik

Upgrading some of the front end features on my site. Have chosen to use Telerik to help me with this.

So if I had a `<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender` I can change this to a Telerik control using  `<telerik:RadWindow Modal="true"` in the same way
I can change `<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload` to `<telerik:RadAsyncUpload`

However, searching online and reading forums I cant find the Telerik equivalent to `<ajaxToolkit:DragPanelExtender`

Does anyone have any idea to what it is?

Comment: Well Spotted!...any idea on an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably RadDock is the control that can help you replace the DragPanelExtender.

Demos: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/dock/examples/dockmode/defaultcs.aspx

Doc: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/dock-overview.html

Comment: RadWindow can do that as well, it also has a ContentTemplate